# IntentService which is started by AlarmManager doesn't work

Tags: java, android, service, alarmmanager, intentservice

I'm trying to get IntentService started by AlarmManager, but the service isn't started.
(Obviously my service is defined in the manifest...)

Here's a little bit of code:

Starting the alarm service:

```
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Main.this, TestsNotification.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(Main.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
             AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
             Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
             calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
             calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
             alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Here's my IntentService:

```
public class TestsNotification extends IntentService {
    public TestsNotification() {
        super("myApp");
    }
    private SharedPreferences settings;
    private final String PREFERENCE_SETTINGS_FILENAME = "Settings";
    private int number=0;
    Tests tests;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_SETTINGS_FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    tests=new Tests();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onStart(intent, startId);
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 return super.onUnbind(intent);
}
public void Notify(String title)
{
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent= new Intent (this,Splash.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    String body = " בליך";
    //String title = "יש מחר מבחן!";
    Notification n =new Notification(R.drawable.test, body, System.currentTimeMillis());
    n.flags |=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    n.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), title, body, pi);
    n.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
    number++;
    n.number=number;
    try {
    nm.notify(0,n);
    FileMethods FM = new FileMethods(this);
    Date current = new Date();
    FM.Write("LOG", "I Dont Care!",FM.Read("LOG", this, "") + current.getDay()+"/"+current.getMonth()+"/"+ current.getYear()+" "+current.getHours()+":"+current.getMinutes() + "Notified" + title+ "\n");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String Attribute = "Class";
    String info = settings.getString(Attribute, "none");
    if(!info.equals("none")) {
        String classLetter = info.substring(0, info.lastIndexOf(" "));
        String classNum1 = info.substring(info.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);
        int classNum = Integer.parseInt(classNum1);
        try {
            Tests nextTest = this.tests.GetTests(classLetter, classNum)[0];
            Date current = new Date();
            Date testDate = new GregorianCalendar(nextTest.getDate().getYear(), nextTest.getDate().getMonth(), Integer.parseInt(nextTest.getDate().getDay())).getTime();
            long difference = testDate.getTime()-current.getTime();
            if (difference <=86400000) {
                Notify("יש מחר מבחן!");
            }//SHOULDNT BE HARDCODED!!!
            else {
                Notify("אין מחר מבחן!!");
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
}
```

FileMethods is just a class to handle File reading and writing (to make sure the AlarmManager runs every 1 day)

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `set()`, there is a 40% chance that you have now specified a time that is in the past.

Also, if the device is asleep at the time, it may fall back asleep before your service is started. There is a very specific pattern for using `_WAKEUP` alarms successfully, involving a `BroadcastReceiver` and a `WakeLock`. My [`WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) tries to handle some of this work for you.

Also, `onStart()` has been deprecated for quite some and should not be implemented on an `IntentService`.

Answer (score 0):

You override `#onCreate()` in your IntentService *without* calling `super.onCreate()`. Don't do that.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_SETTINGS_FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    tests=new Tests();
}
```

The `IntentService` base implementation does a lot of necessary setup in that method (such as initializing the executor & whatnot) required to actually call `IntentService#onHandleIntent(Intent)`.